# Tag-merge or stricter tagging policy? [cryptic-clues] and [cryptic-crosswords]

Tags: tags, tag-synonyms, discussion

Prompted by this question:

- #### [Another Cryptic Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/another-cryptic-crossword)

I wonder if we really should have both tags [cryptic-crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crossword) and [cryptic-clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues). It is confusing to the user searching for examples.

If we want to keep both, then we should enforce the use of [cryptic-crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crossword) only for questions which really combine *mulitple clues* into a *crossword puzzle*.

However, I think, overall, we should discourage posting of individual cryptic-clues as separate puzzles to avoid a spam-flood of such posts.

Instead, several such clues should be combined into a real crossword puzzle (or some other 'combination' of the solutions) to form a bigger, better puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

I think the three tags [cryptic-crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswords), [cryptic-clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues), and [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords) refer to distinct things and each is useful.  I think it's reasonable that a user might want to do an actual complete cryptic crossword puzzle, and use that tag to search for any that have been submitted.  At the same time, a puzzle like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31377/chess-fortnight-is-finally-over) would be an odd result for a user expecting a cryptic crossword, but heavily relies on cryptic clues nonetheless.

I think it's clear that there are fans of cryptic clues around here, whether or not they're used in a standard crossword format, and so they may want to find any puzzle that has a cryptic-clue component.

I think the best way forward is your suggestion to more rigorously apply the tags.  I suggested a couple changes to the tag wikis that might help and will re-tag some myself.

An added issue here is that "cryptic" is similar to "mysterious" or "enigmatic", and so the tag `cryptic-clues` seems to have been applied to a lot of questions that aren't crossword-style cryptic-clues, but are "mysterious", which further confounds things...

Answer (score 3):

I think the two are distinct.  One refers to puzzles using cryptic-crossword-style *clues*, (some puzzles use several of them, and may have other elements as well), while the other refers to actual cryptic crosswords, where there is a grid of words to fill in.

If they are being used incorrectly, it is up to the community to edit the tags.  I just removed [cryptic-crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crossword) from the example you presented, because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Yes, but that is nonsense nevertheless, because we also have a crossword tag on its own, so one can always search/filter for cryptic-clues AND crossword.  On second thought I d say we should merge the cryptic-crossword tag into cryptic-clues and potentially edit some tagging to have crossword as a tag on cryptic-crossword puzzles. Also makes sense as users will find those puzzles when filtering crossword only, which would be natural starting point for many...