# Is it really [good-practice] to have this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I recently discovered that we have a [good-practice](/questions/tagged/good-practice) tag here on PSE meta. It's used on 11 questions, 8 of which are our "Best of [time period]" posts while the other 3 are a strange mix:

- [Tag-merge or stricter tagging policy? [cryptic-clues] and [cryptic-crosswords]](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/tag-merge-or-stricter-tagging-policy-cryptic-clues-and-cryptic-crosswords)
- [Distinctive titles for Only Connect walls?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/distinctive-titles-for-only-connect-walls)
- [Rq custom close reason "literal description" for riddles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/rq-custom-close-reason-literal-description-for-riddles)

I can't see any common feature between these 11 questions. The obvious meaning of a tag called [good-practice](/questions/tagged/good-practice) would be similar to the existing [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) tag, but *none* of the above questions, with the possible exception of the Only Connect one, are actually about good practice. I'm struggling to see *any* point in this tag at all, so I hereby **call for it to be eradicated**.

<sub>(Of course I could simply edit those 11 questions myself, but that [would involve a lot of bumping](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5487/5373), so I'm posting here to meta so that it can be handled by mods. Note that eliminating the [good-practice](/questions/tagged/good-practice) tag doesn't require hard burnination by a CM: it can simply be merged [without synonymising, of course] into the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, which will cause the unwanted tag to smoothly disappear from all questions and from the system.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## I agree, burninate it.

But, not blacklist it yet.

The tag is used by 3 users collectively, 11 questions total, not quite recent, so I don't think it should be really burninated. These questions can then be re-tagged [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette).

Comment: Sure, I never suggested blacklisting it. And most of those 11 questions aren't actually anything to do with etiquette, so they shouldn't be retagged [meta-tag:etiquette] either.